# Player object returning but its properties are undefined

Tags: angular, rest

I am currently using angular7 When I log in to my player, it returns the object. When I however try to view each property, it returns undefined and raising an error. This made all the verbs on this component dysfunctional. Can anyone please assist me in highlighting the problem in my code and steps I should take in order to achieve its function.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Player } from '../models/Player';
import { PlayerService } from '../services/player.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-single-player',
  templateUrl: './single-player.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./single-player.component.scss']
})
export class SinglePlayerComponent implements OnInit {
  loading: boolean;
  player: Player;
  errorMessage: string;

  constructor(private playerService: PlayerService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params) => {
        this.playerService.getSinglePlayer(params.id).subscribe(
          (player: Player) => {
            this.player = player;
            console.log(player._id)
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }


  onModify() {
    this.router.navigate(['/player', 'edit', this.player._id]);
  }

  onDelete() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.playerService.deletePlayer(this.player._id).subscribe(
      () => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      },
      (error) => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.errorMessage = error.message;
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: console.log(player) returns the object, console.log(player._id) returns undefined. What could be wrong with the ngOnInit webhook function contents?

Comment: Can you provide what's actually printed with `console.log(player)`? I would add a breakpoint or `debugger` at this point to inspect the property names and see what's available or even suggested on autocomplete. Incidentally, properties with `_` prefix are usually private so I wonder if that's misleading (or if they are private, then it's right that you can't access it publicly so it's working as expected)

Comment: @JoelBalmer my player object. Structure  player: {_id:"6747544849449", playerName: "antonio"}

Comment: Ok, does console.log(player.playerName) work instead? Also can we see Player class and even  the getSinglePlayer method/whole service. Would be interested to see what type is coming back, whether your Player casting is doing something funky (i.e. if you change return type/subscribe() type to any, does that change anything)?

Comment: It also returns undefined

Comment: Cool, as i say, be interested to see the other things too like Player and PlayerService classes. Additionally whether casting/returning type `any` from the service/in the subscribe method helps (at this point these are just my initial debugging steps).